# Tutorial on how to decode reed-solumn code for QR code

Tags: javascript, qr-code, reed-solomon

http://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/ is a great tutorial on how to encode qr codes and I managed to write an encoder based on it.  Now I am trying to figure out if I add noise if it still properly decodes the message.  Preferably I am looking for something that explains the math instead of just use zxing to decode it.   Unfortunately my Google foo is failing me.

Comment: *"Now I am trying to figure out if I add noise if it still properly decodes the message."* - Wouldn't you do that by comparing the result with whatever you encoded originally?

Comment: No.  You can add about 30% error to the code and it still properly readable.

Comment: For example McDonalds drew a smile in top right of the code.  Still works even though it is an error

Comment: But...doesn't "properly readable" mean "returns the same string that was originally encoded"?  If you get back any other string then it didn't work. In my experience with QR code generation, either the scanner correctly returned the original string or it couldn't read the code, there was no in between.

Comment: Generally that is true.  Though I have seen it give the wrong answer a few times.  The point is I wish to generate a QR code(already done).  I wish to add random noise until just before the code is unreadable and then keep repeating.  It is a statistical analysis thing.  I could use zxing to do the decoding and make this work but I would like to find a tutorial on the math so I know how it actually works instead of just using some code that does it.